# CakePHP redirect on login depending on username

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, authentication

I have a CakePHP 1.3 application that has a login system, which works well. It uses a DB with a users table, which existed before creating this app.

I'm using **Auth** in my **AppController**. The login function looks like

```
function login() {}
```

and it's located in the **users_controller**.

Everything works fine, as I said, but I have problems trying to add a new functionality. I would like to, during the **login** process, detect if a user has introduced a specific combination of *login/password* (let's say *admin/adminpwd*). If so, the login should be succesful AND he would be taken to an admin area (/admin/index). Otherwise, the login process should work as usual.

Once in this admin area (controlled by an **admin_controller**), this user should be able to perform some actions **exclusive to him**, no to the rest of users (even if they type on the browser /admin/*action*).

I've read about ACL, and probably it would help with this, but it seems too complicated for what I really need. Is there any simple way to do this? I guess I should modify the login function, but I don't really know how exactly, and if there's anything else I should change... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just see some code...

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    // we're moving the variable to AppController!

    public function login() {

        $usrInfo = $this->Auth->user();

        if (isset($usrInfo) {

            // this index name might not be right.  I'm going off memory please check this!
            if (in_array($usrInfo['username'], $this->adminUsers)) {
                // do your code here for admin users.  
                // could be a redirect or just changing the layout used
            } else {
                // is a user that is logged in but not in our admin list
            }

    }

}
```

To test if the user is logged in you would need to do something like the following:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    protected $adminUsers = array('joe_blow_uname', 'jane_blow_uname');

    public function beforeFilter() {

        $routing = Configure::read('Routing.admin');
        $usrInfo = $this->Auth->user();

        if (isset($this->params[$routing]) && isset($usrInfo)) {
            if (!in_array($usrInfo['username'], $this->adminUsers)) {
                // do code here for non-admin users using /admin prefix
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Let me know if this doesn't help.

*Or worse breaks something...*

Edit:

This is really not the best way to do this obviously.  ACL or setting up some kind of group in your database would probably be better.  BUT, it is a relatively quick-n-dirty way that, for a small site, should work fine.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried that but nothing happens. It actually seems that whatever is in the `login()` function is not executed (I've done `pr($usrInfo)` to try and nothing is shown. I have this in my AppCOntroller: `$this->Auth->authenticate = ClassRegistry::init('User');`, and a `hashPasswords()` function in the **User** model. I need that to avoid using the **Security.salt** when checking the hashed passwords in the DB, since they are plain **md5** hashed. Anyways, it works fine, but, can this interfere with what you told me to try? Should your code go somewhere else?

Comment: Ok found the reason, I had to do `$this->Auth->redirect = false` in the AppController, and now it's executing the code in `login()`. One more thing though, how can I avoid that a logged user, who isn't an admin, has access to the /admin area?

Comment: @Albert Also, it shouldn't interfere with your model hashing alteration.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you so much. I agree this is not the best way, I'll definitely give ACL a try once I have everything working. Just one more quick question, why if I use **proteced** instead of **var** I get an error? Like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}'...` pointing to that line of code...

Comment: @Albert That is a very good question!  To be honest I've never worked with PHP 4 so the use of `var` is a foreign concept to me.  I understand that it works "as if" you were using `public` but I would need to do some research on this before I could give you an answer.  Otherwise, I'm glad that this worked.  *Also, as an aside you want this at the very least protected to ensure that only `AppController` and classes extending it can manipulate it.  If this were public a crafty-cracker might exploit a bug to add their username to your list*

Comment: so, how should I protect it if I can't use `protected`?

Comment: @Albert Unless you are dealing with a server that is not running PHP 5 I can't imagine a scenario where you couldn't use `protected`.  If you are dealing with PHP 4 then...my suggestion would be to do some research into PHP 4 as I know very little about it, didn't start with PHP until 5.3, and have no desire to dilute my 5.3 knowledge with 4 cruft.

Comment: I'm working with PHP 5, so I don't know what might be going on. I'll try to find out, but I guess this doesn't belong here anymore. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, ACL is pretty complicated (and powerful). But in your case, I'd suggest create a 'group' field in users table to distinguish the role of the user. So you can have more admins later if you want. It's more flexible than hard-code a certain login credential in your `users_controller`.

There are several things you need to do to:

- Tell the Auth component to transfer control to you after the user logins, so you can determine their group and redirect them accordingly.
- Check if a user in a group is accessing some other group's action: If you don't, a regular user just need to be logged in, and they can type in admin url (if they know about it) and they can do everything an admin can. This check will probably be done in `before_something_()` in app_controller or tap into Auth somewhere.

I don't remember all the details, but you can get everything you need in the Cake Cookbook. Good luck!

Comment: thanks gor your reply, but I forgot to say that I can't modify that DB, I just have the information of the users table

Comment: yeah, but definitely do my second suggestion to increase security.